# Why are the Rinkeby and Ropsten testnets named after Swedish locations?

Tags: testnets, ropsten, rinkeby, history

Why are the Rinkeby and Ropsten testnets named after Swedish locations?

I know what they *are* but am wondering why they were named this way.

Comment: Maybe unrelated to Ethereum, but opinion based? I think you were too fast to close this one.

Comment: I don't see how this is even unrelated, and definitely not opinion-based

Comment: This is about a historical fact of why or who named them. That’s what I want to know.

Comment: The question alone is informative in that it conveys the origin of the testnets' names.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Morden: a subway station in London
- Ropsten: a metro station in Stockholm
- Rinkeby: a metro station in Stockholm
- Kovan: a subway station in Singapore

Testnets are named after train stations as a convention, usually where the 
respective testnet maintainers are based from.

sources: [1](https://www.ethnews.com/ethereum-foundation-resets-testnet-morden-ropsten), [2](https://medium.com/@Digix/announcing-kovan-a-stable-ethereum-public-testnet-10ac7cb6c85f)

Comment: Which was also the basis for a funny joke on [April Fools day post]((https://blog.ethereum.org/2017/04/01/ethereum-dev-roundup-q1/)) on the Ethereum blog: "we have launched two new testnets, Qinghuadongluxikou and Hongqiao Airport Terminal 2" =D